# How to call rest service after mule application deployed in cloudhub

Tags: mule

I implemented rest api using mule. I am able to call the api( ex: localhost:8081/getUser) from local machine. I deployed the application in cloudhub. I am calling same api with http://myapp.cloudhub.io/getUser, but it is not working. Could you please guide us, how to rest service after mule application deployed in cloudhub.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `${http.port}` in your in your `mule-app.properties`and **host** set to `0.0.0.0` .
Make sure you did that.
You can check :- https://docs.mulesoft.com/getting-started/deploy-to-cloudhub

Comment: Yes i did that. I am calling rest service as http://myapp.cloudhub.io/getUser. Here getUser is my rest service. its working if I set host to localhost and port to 8081 than i am able to call localhost:8081/getUser and I am getting user details as response. But I dont know how to call after deploying mule application in cloudhub. I called as http://myapp.cloudhub.io/getUser. But I am getting page cant be found error. Coud you please guide me how to call rest service after application deployed in cloudhub Note: host set to 0.0.0.0 and port set to ${http.port}

Comment: facing same issue, please post the answer if it is resolved.